# Remove first N fields separated by delimiter

Tags: regex, vim, vi

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,,,,
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,,,,
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,,,,
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,,,,
```

assuming fN it's some sequence of characters except `,`.

How to remove first 3 fields?

so far I've tried `%s/^.*,.*,.*,//` but it removes whole line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assume your cursor at the first line, first column. also the fields have same width (as your example shows)

You could press the below key sequence (6 keystrokes ):

```
<Ctrl-V>G3f,x
```

If the fields have different length, you could:

record macro with `q` :

```
qq0v3f,xjq
```

then, replay the macro, for example, 99 times:

```
99@q
```

or do it in command line:

```
%s/\v^([^,]*,){3}//
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `\v` means?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut`, use the delimiter option `d,` (set `,` as delimiter), and then select what you want `-f4-` (out all fields from 4 to the end...)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `*` modifier is *greedy*, i.e. it matches *all characters* it can get.

Either restrict the values to any character **except the comma delimiter**: `[^,]`:

```
:%s/^\([^,]*,\)\{3}//
```

or use the non-greedy variant `.\{-}`:

```
:%s/^\(.\{-},\)\{3}//
```

### Alternative

For comma-separated values (CSV) file handling, you may also be interested in the [csv.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830), which offers a `:DeleteColumn` command.